# Unable to get property 'value' from search bar after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Upon pressing the search button, my code is supposed to save the input of the search bar into a variable and attach it to a Google link. The function should only execute when pressing the button.

I was successful before but the only difference that time was I put the "`onclick`" in the HTML tags. It seems like this code is not working because the function `searchExplore()` is executed although the button has not been clicked yet, therefore, making the value of the search input equal null or undefined.

When I used the Google Dev Tools to debug it, it immediately gave me an error:

> Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

This happened before I even clicked the button.

```js
document.getElementById('searchbtn').onclick = searchExplore();

function searchExplore(){
 var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
 document.getElementById('searchform').action = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+input;
}
```

```css
body{
}
.search{
  text-align:center;
  background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding:20px;
  }
form{
  display:inline-flex;
}
#searchbar{
  font-size:35px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 0 0 20px;
  border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  }
#searchbtn{
  font-size:35px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 90px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#searchbar:hover,#searchbar:focus{
  box-shadow:-3px 3px 15px;
}
#searchbtn:hover,#searchbtn:focus{
  box-shadow:-.1px 3px 15px 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mypen1.css" type="text/css"/>
  <title>MJ Search</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mypen1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="search">
    <form id="searchform" action="">
         <input id="searchbar" type= "search" placeholder="Search & Explore..."/>
         <button id="searchbtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: because you are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the click handler....

Comment: Why did my question get a down vote, I have all the necessary content to understand my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line.

```
document.getElementById('searchbtn').onclick = searchExplore();
```

You are calling `searchExplore` and then returning the result to the `onclick` handler.

You probably want to assign the function itself to the onclick handler - so don't call your function here.

```
document.getElementById('searchbtn').onclick = searchExplore;
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It is giving me a new error: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference. The only code I have changed from above is the searchExplore( ); to searchExplore; like you prescribed.

Comment: You need to also have this code run *after* the elements have been generated on the DOM. This will mean either moving your script block after the elements, or running this code on a document loaded callback etc.

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by running the javascript before initializing the button. To fix this, just transfer your Javascript code below the form. This is to remove that error.

See script below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mypen1.css" type="text/css"/>
  <title>MJ Search</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mypen1.js"></script>
  <style>
    body{
        }
        .search{
          text-align:center;
          background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png");
          background-size:cover;
          background-position: center;
          padding:20px;
          }
        form{
          display:inline-flex;
        }
        #searchbar{
          font-size:35px;
          border: 0;
          padding: 0px 0 0 20px;
          border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
          outline: 0;
          font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
          }
        #searchbtn{
          font-size:35px;
          border: 0;
          padding: 10px;
          border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
          outline: 0;
          width: 90px; 
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        #searchbar:hover,#searchbar:focus{
          box-shadow:-3px 3px 15px;
        }
        #searchbtn:hover,#searchbtn:focus{
          box-shadow:-.1px 3px 15px 1px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="search">
    <form id="searchform" action="">
         <input id="searchbar" type= "search" placeholder="Search & Explore..."/>
         <button id="searchbtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div> 
</body>  
 
<script>    
document.getElementById('searchbtn').onclick = searchExplore();

function searchExplore(){
 var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
 document.getElementById('searchform').action = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+input;
}
</script>
```